# Multi-page output :: text select with tmux over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux, copy-paste, less

I have a **local** terminal within **tmux**. Now I connect to a remote server via SSH and run some command piped to **less**. With **tmux** I can easily select part or the entire screen, however I can not select text on the next page (that is not visible now), since there's no way to scroll down the output of **less** while keeping **tmux** in text selection mode.

Of course I can paste from different buffers of **tmux**, but that is kinda ugly.

Is there any better solution?